# Run button greyed out phpstorm8

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I just installed phpstorm8 and created an empty project with a simple javascript file. The javascript file just has a console.log statement. However the run button is greyed out and i could not find out what configuration to run this in.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It is greyed out because it requires Run/Debug Configuration to be created and selected first. Use that drop down box next to Run button to create one of correct type.

Comment: @LazyOne got it figured out, thanks for your help.